# How to replace selectors in scss file while compilatioon

Tags: css, sass, node-sass, gulp-ruby-sass, node-sass-chokidar

This is my scss file - https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-javascript-ui-controls/blob/master/controls/buttons/styles/button/_layout.scss#L3

In above i have used `{#{&}` but i want to replace that with empty string while compiling to css [ based on specific params it has to be replaced ].

Is there any possibility to  the same in scss compilatio

Comment: Did you look at gulp-replace? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace

Comment: @Mark, not this. i want any mwehods which can do the same in scss